# Construct MediaStore URI for specific folder

Tags: android

For example if a have two directories `/sdcard/Music/Music-1` and `/sdcard/Music/Music-2` how can I construct a URI to get the files in `Music-1` dir for example. I can use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to get the content of all external storage but how to do the trick only for specific dir.

Answer (score 3):

Filter the path from the `DATA` field and construct a poper `SELECT WHERE` statement to match the folder names, you can use `SUBSTR` in the query ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
>                    uri1, Selection, 
>                    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
>                    new String[] {str}, null);
> ```

You might need to use `"%"+str+"%"` instead, because "Music-1" is just part of the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA`.

Comment: How do you do you get str from a Uri?

Answer (score 2):

Do exactly this,

```
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri1, Selection, 
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
            new String[] {str},
            null);
```

Comment: How do you do you get str from a Uri?