# Get MediaStore path of a Specific Folder

Tags: android, gridview, mediastore, android-ion

I'm creating an update for my application, in it I have a folder with saved images that I would like to display in a GridView.  I am already using the [Ion library](https://github.com/koush/ion).  The creator of the library (Koush Dutta) already has a sample doing what I want and displays all of the images from the [SD Card in a GridView.](https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion-sample/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/sample/GallerySample.java).

What I want to do is display only the images from a specific folder on my SD Card (called comics) in the GridView.  I am using the code directly from the sample above, only modifying some names.

**My Problem** is that I cannot get only the images from the SD Card into the GridView, currently it gets all the images from the SD Card.  I want only from the folder /sdcard/Comics/

**Code**

```
public class SavedComics extends Activity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    // Adapter to populate and imageview from an url contained in the array adapter
    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // see if we need to load more to get 40, otherwise populate the adapter
            if (position > getCount() - 4)
                loadMore();

            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image, null);

            // find the image view
            final ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comic);

            // select the image view
            Ion.with(iv)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .load(getItem(position));

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

        int cols = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi * 2;
        GridView view = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.results);
        view.setNumColumns(cols);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        view.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadMore();
    }

    Cursor mediaCursor;
    public void loadMore() {
        if (mediaCursor == null) {
            mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), null, null, null, null);
        }

        int loaded = 0;
        while (mediaCursor.moveToNext() && loaded < 10) {
            // get the media type. ion can show images for both regular images AND video.
            int mediaType = mediaCursor.getInt(mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE));
            if (mediaType != MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
                && mediaType != MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                continue;
            }

            loaded++;

            String uri = mediaCursor.getString(mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
            File file = new File(uri);
            // turn this into a file uri if necessary/possible
            if (file.exists())
                mAdapter.add(file.toURI().toString());
            else
                mAdapter.add(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a few things, one being something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5646849/1064310):

```
getContentResolver().query(
                   uri1, Selection, 
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
                   new String[] {str}, null);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just figured it out with help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039779/displaying-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-the-sdcard-using-a-gridview).

Turns out all you need to do is use this code below to get the cursor, and it will only load images from the `/sdcard/comics/` folder.

Note that I tested this with the Ion library and your code, and it worked for me!

```
mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
    null,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    new String[] {"%comics%"},
    null
);
```

Comment: "This constant was deprecated in API level 29. Apps may not have filesystem permissions to directly access this path. Instead of trying to open this path directly, apps should use ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(Uri, String) to gain access" from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#summary