# Query images from SDCard and display them in a GridView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gridview, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to wrap my around this problem. I have some code that uses a CursorLoader to query images from the sdcard and display them in a GridView with a help of a SimpleCursorAdapter. I followed some examples online and read through the documentation. I know I got part things right. The code runs without any errors, however I cannot get the thumbnails to display on the grid. Following is the code I have gotten so far:

GalleryFragment.java

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    public static final int PHOTO_LIST_ID = 0x01;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        // Bind adapter to grid
        setupCursorAdapter();
        // Initialize the loader with a special ID and the defined callbacks
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PHOTO_LIST_ID,
                new Bundle(), imageLoader);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;

    }

    private void setupCursorAdapter() {
        String[] from = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
        int[] to = {R.id.imageView};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.gallery_image_item,
                null, from, to,
                0);
    }

    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> imageLoader =
            new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {

                @Override
                public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                    // Define the columns to retrieve
                    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};
                    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, null, null, null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
                    adapter.swapCursor(data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
                    adapter.swapCursor(null);
                }
            };
}
```

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.sfsu.csc780.pictachio.GalleryFragment">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

gallery_image_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="ImageView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I read in many places, that RecyclerView is the recommended approach instead of a GridView. I had given a shot at it, but I didn't know what kind of model to create for this. Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The code in this question worked for me, I got it running in order to answer the question (uses a library though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407581/get-mediastore-path-of-a-specific-folder

Comment: Interesting. I haven't considered using libraries for this. Thanks for the share.

Comment: I do not see code where it can get images in a directory. I will get you a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the use of getLoaderManager() and initLoader() for getting images. One way is to get them from the SQLite database. A proper Google documentation is @ [SQL query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). I provide a sample code using that query method. However I never had to get images in Android.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] cols = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,  // get the image
};
//String where = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, cols, null, null, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   int column_image = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   res = cursor.getString(column_image);
}
cursor.close();
```

Notes:

- The third and fourth parameter of `query`() is useful for filtering the returned data.
- The `cursor` object is returned from query and it can be traversed, sample code is listed above.
- Another interesting way is to use @ [getExternalStorageDirectory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) of class **Environment**. I have used it to *find files in a specific directory*. This technique may actually be faster since it searches in a specific directory instead of querying the database. However there may be undesired permission issues especially with the SD card.

Try it out, and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Is there a way to bind the images fetched to a RecyclerView ViewHolder?

Comment: @vshl, RecyclerView is simply a GUI component/class. It has nothing to do with getting images. You still have get images from a database or the native file system. I see no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) library. It is so simple. Just add library dependency to your project and then put below lines to your class. Your adapter is ready, you can set it for your gridview.

```
RecentImages ri = new RecentImages();
ImageAdapter adapter = ri.getAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

It has some option for customizing your query on images.