# How to get images from SD-Card via cursor

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am puzzling here to get my images into a gallery.

I take a photo and save it to:

`/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/myFolder`

I want to get the images there via cursor:

```
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID);
```

Problem is that I can only get the images which are original saved within

`/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100LDDSC`

How can I get images within other folders?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407581/get-mediastore-path-of-a-specific-folder

Comment: Why is this not working?

Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/storage/"));
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri,
                columns, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID);