# Accessing recent images in a folder using MediaStore

Tags: java, android, image, android-cursor, mediastore

I am currently using this code to access the recent images from `/DCIM/` folder -

```java
final Cursor cursor = chatActivity.this.getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                        null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

and then get the images by

```java
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
    File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
    }
}
```

and then using `cursor.moveToNext()` to access the next image.

But if I have to access the images in another folder (like `/MyFolder/Images/`) in a similar fashion, using `MediaStore` and `Cursor` then what should be done?

I have looked at [Get MediaStore path of a Specific Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407581/get-mediastore-path-of-a-specific-folder) and [Displaying images from a specific folder on the SDCard using a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039779/displaying-images-from-a-specific-folder-on-the-sdcard-using-a-gridview), they don't answer my question.

Comment: Can I see your `projection` initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code you are not only getting images from `/DCIM/` folder but from all folders. If you want to get images from specific folder you can use something like this:

```
final Cursor cursor = chatActivity.this.getContentResolver()
                .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ?",
                        "%" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/%", MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

Comment: Thank you! I only changed `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` to `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`

Comment: @CoolCoder That's correct. I made a mistake in that argument. Edited.